# Three in a row: Tic, Tac, Toe

Tags: java, object-oriented, game, tic-tac-toe

The other day, I started thinking of a new personal project to start that I wanted to do in Java. As I started to do it, I realized that I was constantly deleting classes, creating new ones, merging them, etc. I finally have come to the conclusion that my understanding of OOP is not very strong.

To practice, I thought the best thing to do would be to start with something simple. For that, I chose the game Tic Tac Toe.

**Main.java**

```
package com.sirpython.tictactoe;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TicTacToeGame game = new TicTacToeGame();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true) {
            game.getBoard().display();
            System.out.println("\nIt is " + game.getTurn().getSymbol() + "'s turn.");

            int space = input.nextInt(10);

            if(space < game.MIN_SPACE || space > game.MAX_SPACE) {
                System.out.println("Please choose a space 0-8");
                continue;
            }

            try {
                game.place(space);
            } catch(OccupiedSpaceException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                continue;
            }

            Player winner = game.getWinner();

            if(winner != null) {
                System.out.println("Winner: " + winner.getSymbol());
                break;
            }

            game.switchTurns();
        }
    }
}
```

**TicTacToeGame.java**

```
package com.sirpython.tictactoe;

public class TicTacToeGame {
    public final int MIN_SPACE = 0;
    public final int MAX_SPACE = 8;

    private final int[][] winConditions = { {0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8}, {0,3,6}, {1,4,7}, {2,5,8}, {0,4,8}, {2,4,6} };
    private final Space[][] winSpaces;

    private Board board;
    private Player turn;

    public TicTacToeGame() {
        board = new Board();
        turn = Player.X;
        winSpaces = new Space[winConditions.length][winConditions[0].length];

        for(int i = 0; i < winConditions.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < winConditions[i].length; j++) {
                winSpaces[i][j] = board.getSpace(winConditions[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Attempts to place a player on a space
     * @param space The space to place at
     * @throws OccupiedSpaceException The desired space is taken
     */
    public void place(int space) throws OccupiedSpaceException {
        if(!board.isFree(space)) {
            throw new OccupiedSpaceException();
        }

       board.getSpace(space).setOccupant(getTurn());
    }

    /**
     * Returns the Player whose turn it is
     * @return The Player whose turn it is
     */
    public Player getTurn() {
        return turn;
    }

    /**
     * Switches whose turn it is.
     *
     * If it's X's turn, it's now O's.
     * If it's O's turn, it's now X's.
     */
    public void switchTurns() {
        if(turn == Player.X) {
            turn = Player.O;
        } else if(turn == Player.O) {
            turn = Player.X;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the winner if there is one
     * @return The winner or null
     */
    public Player getWinner() {
        for(int i = 0; i < winSpaces.length; i++) {
            Player[] occupants = {winSpaces[i][0].getOccupant(),
                                  winSpaces[i][1].getOccupant(),
                                  winSpaces[i][2].getOccupant()};

            if(occupants[0] == occupants[1] && occupants[1] == occupants[2]) {
                return occupants[0];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the board associated with this game
     * @return The board
     */
    public Board getBoard() {
        return board;
    }
}
```

**Board.java**

```
package com.sirpython.tictactoe;

public class Board {
    public final int SIZE = 9;
    public final int ROW_SIZE = 3;

    private final Space[] spaces;

    public Board() {
        spaces = new Space[SIZE];

        for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            spaces[i] = new Space();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displays the board in the form of a normal Tic Tac Toe board
     */
    public void display() {
        for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {

            Player occupant = spaces[i].getOccupant();

            /* If there is nothing occupying the space, print the space's number */
            char toPrint = occupant == null ? (char) (i + '0') : occupant.getSymbol();

            /* Print out a newline every third iteration so it looks like a tictactoe board */
            System.out.print((i % ROW_SIZE == 0 && i != 0 ? "\n" : "") + toPrint);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Tells if a space is occupied
     * @param space The number of the space to check
     * @return If the space is occupied
     */
    public boolean isFree(int space) {
        return spaces[space].getOccupant() == null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the space
     * @param space The number of the space
     * @return The space
     */
    public Space getSpace(int space) {
        return spaces[space];
    }
}
```

**Space.java**

```
package com.sirpython.tictactoe;

public class Space {
    private Player occupant = null;

    public Space() {
    }

    /**
     * Sets the occupant field
     * @param occupant The new value for the field
     */
    public void setOccupant(Player occupant) {
        this.occupant = occupant;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the occupant field
     * @return The occupant field value
     */
    public Player getOccupant() {
        return occupant;
    }
}
```

**Player.java**

```
package com.sirpython.tictactoe;

public enum Player {
    X('x'), O('o');

    private final char symbol;
    private Player(char symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    /**
     * Returns this Player's symbol
     * @return This Player's symbol
     */
    public char getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }
}
```

**OccupiedSpaceException.java**

```
package com.sirpython.tictactoe;

public class OccupiedSpaceException extends Exception {
    public OccupiedSpaceException() {
        super("That space is already occupied");
    }
}
```

---

## Sample

Here is a sample game I played with myself:

> ```
> 012
> 345
> 678
> It is x's turn.
> 0 <--
> x12
> 345
> 678
> It is o's turn.
> 4 <--
> x12
> 3o5
> 678
> It is x's turn.
> 6 <--
> x12
> 3o5
> x78
> It is o's turn.
> 7 <--
> x12
> 3o5
> xo8
> It is x's turn.
> 3 <--
> Winner: x
> ```

Yay! I beat myself!

*Note: The numbers pointed to by an `<--` are user input.*

## Concerns

- As questioned above, how is this code, OOP-wise? Do classes do what they should do and nothing else? Should some classes be refactored?
- How is my handling of the win (`TicTacToe.java`)? Is it a good idea to have an entire variable dedicated to hold the square numbers that form a win condition so that it can be used to get the actual square/space? And, should this be in a `static` block rather than the constructor?
- How is my documentation? I was using the IntelliJ IDEA, which automatically generates a docstring for me to fill out. However, are there any practices that I am missing? I've occasionally seen HTML tags being used.
- How is my connection between the classes? As in, is the way that my classes are talking to each other wise? I am mainly concerned about the `main` methods interaction with `TicTacToeGame`, and that class's interaction with `Board`.
- Is my code idiomatic? I am not very familiar at all with Java, so I often have the API docs up in my browser as I am programming (is this bad?). Are there any classes that I could have used to simplify my code?
- If I were writing this in a non-OOP language, I probably would've stored the two players in an array and done some tricks (`turn = (turn + 1) % 2`) to find out whose turn it was. However, since this in an OOP language and it's Java, I thought it would be best to store the players in an enum. Is this the best choice, or would it have been better to create an entire class?
- I created my own exception for handling occupied spaces. Would it have been better to use a built-in exception?

Any other things that jump out are encouraged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How is code, OO-wise? Do classes do what they should do and nothing else? Should some classes be refactored?

The `Main` class sticks out like a sore thumb.
For one thing, "Main" doesn't mean anything.
`TicTacToeRunner` would be better.
More important, it has intimate knowledge of how the game works.
It would be better to move most of the content of `Main.main` into `TicTacToeGame.play` (a new static method I'm proposing), for example.
The `TicTacToeRunner` could be in charge of setting up input streams and passing what's necessary for `TicTacToeGame.play`.
This will also make it possible to unit test.

> How is my handling of the win (TicTacToe.java)? Is it a good idea to have an entire variable dedicated to hold the square numbers that form a win condition so that it can be used to get the actual square/space? And, should this be in a static block rather than the constructor?

`winConditions` will be the same for every single instance.
So clearly it should be static.

I don't think `winSpaces` really buys you much.
It just takes space for little benefit if any.
I think you can refactor using just `winConditions` to determine a winner.

> How is my documentation? [...] Are there any practices that I am missing? I've occasionally seen HTML tags being used.

Most of the docstrings are on getters and setters,
which are trivial.
I don't think a docstring is necessary at all for those.
The non-trivial cases are fine.

Not feeling the need for HTML in a docstring is a good thing. Simple.

> How is my connection between the classes? As in, is the way that my classes are talking to each other wise? I am mainly concerned about the main methods interaction with `TicTacToeGame`, and that class's interaction with Board.

I already pointed out above about `Main` -> `TicTacToeGame`.

Chained calls like `game.getBoard().display()` in `Main` are a warning sign of poor information hiding: `Main` knows that `Game` has a `Board`, and the `display` method of the board. Calling from `Main`, `game.display()` would be better, hiding the internal details of `game` calling `this.board.display()`.

If you move these operations out of `Main` into `Game` as I suggested,
then `game.getBoard().display()` becomes OK,
as you'll be inside the `Game` class,
so it's normal that it knows such internal details.

Actually, it would be best if `game.getBoard()` disappeared:
nobody else really needs to know about the board.
And if yes, probably a defensive copy should be returned to prevent tampering with the board outside of the game.

> Is my code idiomatic?

More or less.

The loop in `getWinner` would be more idiomatic as an enhanced for-each.

The custom exception seems a bit over-engineered.
You could make `place` return a boolean to indicate success/failure.
I think that way would be better,
because it will do the job but simpler.

> I am not very familiar at all with Java, so I often have the API docs up in my browser as I am programming (is this bad?).

I look at the JavaDoc all the time.
Occasionally the tutorials too, like [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/highlevel.html).
And the [source code too](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/StringBuilder.java#StringBuilder),
to know how stuff is implemented.
Is this bad?

> If I were writing this in a non-OOP language, I probably would've stored the two players in an array and done some tricks (turn = (turn + 1) % 2) to find out whose turn it was. However, since this in an OOP language and it's Java, I thought it would be best to store the players in an enum. Is this the best choice, or would it have been better to create an entire class?

A traditional 2-player tic-tac-toe game has two players.
A more OOP way would have been that the game is initialized with two players,
and it would track them in separate fields,
for example `firstPlayer`, `secondPlayer`.

Also, some odd elements:

- A "symbol" is not a player. A symbol is a symbol, players use symbols
- A "turn" is not a player

I would prefer switching turns like this, given `Player currentPlayer`:

```
if (currentPlayer == firstPlayer) {
    currentPlayer = secondPlayer;
} else {
    currentPlayer = firstPlayer;
}
```

> Any other things that jump out are encouraged.

A few other suggestions:

- The "get" prefix is typically used for simple getters that just return the value of a member variable (or defensive copy). `getWinner` is more involved, so the "get" prefix is misleading. Perhaps `calculateWinner` or `checkWinner` would be better.
- Instead of `setOccupant` and `getOccupant` I'd go for `setPlayer` and `getPlayer`
- Is the empty constructor of `Space` necessary there?
- In `switchTurns`, not having an `else` is odd. It would be better to convert the last `else if` to an `else`. Or you might add an `else` that throws `IllegalStateException`.